# How to create multiple previews of a composable in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

An Android Jetpack composable may have parameters and it would be great to have multiple previews of a single composable to see how it works with different arguments. Let's take for example a simple composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GreetingText(name: String) {
    Text("Hello $name!")
}
```

A preview might look like this:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun GreetingTextPreview() {
    GreetingText("John")
}
```

How can I preview the composable using different names without creating multiple previews?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Single preview composable

A straightforward way is to combine multiple composables in a single preview, for example:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingTextPreview() {
    Column {
        val names = remember {
            arrayOf("John", "D'Artagnan")
        }

        for (name in names) {
            GreetingText(name)
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

#### Multiple previews using PreviewParameter

It might not be convenient to combine multiple composables into a single preview if the composable is too large for example. An alternative way is to use a [PreviewParameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/tooling/preview/PreviewParameter), this way you'll get separate previews:

```kotlin
class NameProvider: PreviewParameterProvider<String> {
    override val values: Sequence<String> = sequenceOf(
        "John",
        "Albert Einstein"
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingTextPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(NameProvider::class) name: String
) {
    GreetingText(name)
}
```

And the result:

[image]

But keep in mind that you're limited to have only one `@PreviewParameter` per preview composable.

Comment: Great tip! I can recommend using this approach to automatically generate a light theme and dark theme option for my previews with `    @PreviewParameter(PreviewThemeProvider::class) useDarkTheme: Boolean
` and a `PreviewParameterProvider<Boolean>` with `false, true` which removes a lot of boilerplate code.